# Ext.data.Store.getById failed

Tags: extjs

I have a store which is defined something like this:

```
var AdditionalGridData = new Ext.data.JsonStore(
                {                       root: "result",
                    data: { result: Ext.decode(this.Data.AdditionalGridData) },
                    idProperty: 'iD',
                    fields: [
                            { name: "iD", type: "int", allowBlank: false }, //must match selected row's primary key
                            {name: "SomeText", type: "string" }
                        ]
                });
```

So there is a time when I want to get an existing record by it's ID value. I call getById and it returns undefined. The store really contains the record that I am searching. Why could it not return my record?
Read somewhere on the forums that:
you need to pass record id (f.e. "ext-record-1") to Store.getById instead of your data ID (f.e. "1");
Is this correct? Where do I get that record id?

Comment: the id is the data id. If the record is new meaning the id isn't set then ext generates a phantom id. How do you know that the data is there?

Comment: It's also worth noting that the ID will need to be set in the metaData for the store also

Comment: To Robby: I know it is there because if it isn't then I create it. I've also tried:
var records = AdditionalGridData.query("iD", CurrentID+"", false, true);
but that also didn't help!

Comment: To Jaitsu: what do you mean by metaData?

Comment: nevermind, I missed your fields definition, that is your metaData

Comment: I am inserting data to the store like this: 
var r = new Ext.data.Record({SomeText:"some random text"},{iD:CurrentID});
AdditionalGridData.add(r);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was inserting the records incorrectly. I was inserting them like .add({ContactName:"aaa"},{ContactID:1}), and should have done it like .add({ContactName:"aaa"}, 1);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var additionalDataRecord = Ext.data.Record.create([
    {name: 'iD', type: 'int', allowBlank: false},
    {name: 'someText', type: 'string'}
]);

var additionalDataReader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
    root: 'result',
    id: 'iD'
}, additionalDataRecord);

then in your data store declaration, specify

reader: additionalDataReader
```

Comment: that's the same what I've defined